# How to get spectrum for the whole period of time of music signal using librosa?

Tags: python, signal-processing, librosa

I have decided to use [librosa](https://librosa.github.io/) for analyzing music signals and extracting required features. Currently, I am trying to visualize spectrum of music for the whole time. I found in the library this [method](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.stft.html#librosa.core.stft) that does STFT and returns the spectrum. But one returns matrix where spectrum calculated for particular frames, not for all time.

Is it possible to compute spectrum for the whole time using this library, maybe somehow process given matrix or there is a special method in librosa for this purpose?

If no -- Could you please suggest another library?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> But one returns matrix where spectrum calculated for particular frames, not for all time.

It does calculate for the whole duration. The reason for the returned matrix being shorter is because each **frame** is computed over window of **samples** (e.g. 2048)

You can convert between the units using
[`frames_to_samples`](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.frames_to_samples.html).

Comment: are you able to help here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48220514/finding-speed-and-tone-of-speech-in-an-audio-using-python thanks